# Database cleaner not working with vim-rspec plugin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, vim, rspec, database-cleaner

I use vim-rspec plugin to be able to run rspec tests from within vim, and it was working very well so far. But suddenly the `database_cleaner` gem stopped working. 
Here is my configuration:

```
# spec/rspec_rails.rb
Rspec.configure do |config|
    config.before(:suite) do
        puts "Setting up the database cleaner."
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
        DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    config.around(:each) do |example|
        puts "Cleaning the database"
        DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
            example.run
        end
    end
end
```

I put those two messages to find out if the two blocks run. but they don't. Even if I stop `spring` than I run again it does not correct it. The strange thing is that if I run the `rspec` command from the command line every thing works well and I get both of the messages and the database cleaned, the first one time on running, and the second on every example run.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be in `spring` itself, remove it and try again. Also you can take a look at a `g:rspec_command` in your `.vimrc` file, maybe you bind any specific script to it?